# Simple Perl websocket client

Tags: perl, websocket, client

I am trying to write a simple websocket client in Perl:

```perl
use Protocol::WebSocket::Client;

my $client = Protocol::WebSocket->new(url => 'ws://myserver:port');

# Sends a correct handshake header
$client->connect;

# Register on connect handler
$client->on(
    connect => sub {
        $client->write('hi there');
    }
);

# Parses incoming data and on every frame calls on_read
$client->read($reply);
print "$reply\n";

# Sends correct close header
$client->disconnect;
```

as shown in [the documentation for `Protocol::WebSocket::Client`](http://search.cpan.org/~vti/Protocol-WebSocket-0.18/lib/Protocol/WebSocket/Client.pm),
but I receive the message:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Protocol::WebSocket" at ./webSocketClient.pl.
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: As you're going to need a lot of trying to get this to work, maybe you should look into alternatives. https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client seems promising.

Comment: The author of the module emailed this to me: *"I wanted to comment, but I don't have enough reputation or whatever it is called. [A good client example is here](https://github.com/vti/protocol-websocket/blob/master/util/wsconsole)."*

Answer (score 7):

[`Protocol::WebSocket`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Protocol::WebSocket) is a low-level implementation of [*WebSocket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) protocol. It doesn't contain the code that sends/receives data; it just parses the protocol messages.

You might want to look into examples for using `Protocol::WebSocket` with various modules, see `examples`. A good client example is implemented in the `wsconsole` utility which comes with this module.

There are several high-level modules on CPAN that implement WebSockets hiding all low level stuff, and most of them use `Protocol::WebSocket`. Take a look at [`AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client) or [`Net::Async::WebSocket::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Async::WebSocket::Client).

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in the example code. `Protocol::WebSocket->new` should be `Protocol::WebSocket::Client->new`

Comment: Good find. Are you going to fix it and make a pr?

Comment: @simbabque: I've emailed the author. But I'm not going to submit a fix as the sample is still broken with that correction and I'm unclear how to fix it.

Comment: I see. The documentation is sparse at best, too.

Comment: @simbabque: It is. And I should clarify that by *broken* I mean incomplete. It has things like `...get non-blocking socket...` and `...do smth with read data...` which prevent it from compiling. It's ten years since I did any Sockets programming, and I would be more than likely to get it wrong if I attempted to fill those gaps.

Comment: The above code is giving me error "Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Protocol/WebSocket/Client.pm line 103." on windows.