# How to write a client program for Net::WebSocket::Server program?

Tags: perl, websocket, client-server

I have a server program that listens on 9000 port. But I can't find a way to write a client program for that server that connects server at 9000 port. Here is the main part of server program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::WebSocket::Server;
    
my $port = "9000";
my $msg_count = 0;

print "starting server on $port \n\n";

my $count = 2400;

Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
    listen => $port,
    silence_max => 5,

    tick_period => 300,
    on_tick => sub {
        my ($serv) = @_;    
        print "connections >> " . $serv->connections . "\n";    
        print $_->ip() for( $serv->connections() ); print "\n";
        print $_->port() for( $serv->connections() ); print "\n\n";
        $count++;    
    },

    on_connect => sub {
        my ($serv, $conn) = @_;
        $conn->on(   

        handshake => sub {
                my ($conn, $handshake) = @_;
                my $tmp = $handshake->req->origin;
                print "here ... $tmp \n\n";    
        },

            utf8 => sub {
                my ($conn, $msg) = @_;
                my $IP = $conn->ip();
                my $PORT = $conn->port();
                my $SERVER = $conn->server();
                my $SOCKET = $conn->socket();
                my $str = Dumper $SOCKET;
```

I searched internet and what that sounds understandable to me is the following client program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $cl=IO::Socket::SSL->new("http://localhost:9000") or die "error=$!, ssl_error=$SSL_ERROR"; 
if($cl) {
    $cl->connect_SSL or die $@;
    # Something about certificates?
    $cl->syswrite("Command");
    close($cl);
}
```

But its not working. The error client program generates is as follows:

```
Expected 'PeerService' at client2.pl line 5.
```

I am newbie in Socket programming and currently understanding websockets programming in Perl.

Note: I am on windows platform.

I ran the example code suggested [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318581/simple-perl-websocket-client.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318581/simple-perl-websocket-client) It gives error "Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Protocol/WebSocket/Client.pm line 103.":

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Protocol::WebSocket::Client;

my $client = Protocol::WebSocket::Client->new(url => 'ws://localhost:9000') or die "$!";
my $reply = "Free\n";
# Sends a correct handshake header
$client->connect or die "$!";

# Register on connect handler
$client->on(
    connect => sub {
        $client->write('hi there');
    }
) or die "$!";

# Parses incoming data and on every frame calls on_read
$client->read($reply);
print "$reply\n";

# Sends correct close header
$client->disconnect;
```

Comment: 1. Websockets are neither plain TCP sockets nor plain SSL sockets. 2. IO::Socket::SSL usage is completely off, see documentation on how to use it. In short: it does not get a URL as destination. 3. There are [easy to find examples for websocket client in perl](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+websocket+client+example). 4. Possible duplicate of [Simple Perl websocket client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318581/simple-perl-websocket-client)

Comment: The example of stack post code gives me following error "Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Protocol/WebSocket/Client.pm line 103."

Comment: Looks like it also needs to have a handler for `write` and `read` as shown in the [documentation of the module](https://metacpan.org/release/VTI/Protocol-WebSocket-0.18/view/lib/Protocol/WebSocket/Client.pm). Also note the comments in the linked question where they mention AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client and also link to an example on how to use it.

Comment: Your server does not utilize SSL (you need provide certificates for SSL communication), on other side you try to utilize SSL communication on client side -- how do you expect they will understand each other? Perhaps in your question you should start with stating your goal -- I want to establish secure/insecure communication between server working on port `#` and network client to pass information of following type. I came up with following _server_ code but can not achieve desired result with following _client_.

Comment: (continuation of previous comment) I have tested the communication with web browser and [nc](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/nc.1.html) what confirms that server works properly.

Comment: Reference: [perl - Socket programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_socket_programming.htm), [perl - Socket programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-socket-programming/)

Answer (score 2):

Please investigate following demo code snippets for `WebSocket` *Server* and *Client*.

Note: please do not forget to alter code to match your **server origin** (ip address and port)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Net::WebSocket::Server;

my $origin = 'http://192.168.1.160:8080';  # server origin
my $port = 8080;

$| = 1;

say "Starting server on $port";

Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
    listen => $port,
    tick_period => 60,
    on_tick => sub {
        my ($serv) = @_;
        my $stamp = 'Server time: ' . scalar localtime;
        $_->send_utf8($stamp) for $serv->connections;
    },
    on_connect => sub {
        my ($serv, $conn) = @_;
        $conn->on(
            handshake => sub {
                my ($conn, $handshake) = @_;
                $conn->disconnect() unless $handshake->req->origin eq $origin;
            },
            ready => sub {
                my ($conn) = @_;
                say "Client: connect IP $conn->{ip} PORT $conn->{port}";
                my $msg = 'Connected server time is ' . scalar localtime . "\n";
                $_->send_utf8($msg) for $conn->server->connections;
            },
            utf8 => sub {
                my ($conn, $msg) = @_;
                say "Client message: $conn->{ip} $msg";
                $_->send_utf8('Server reply: ' . $msg)
                        for $conn->server->connections;
                $conn->disconnect() if $msg eq 'exit';
            },
            binary => sub {
                my ($conn, $msg) = @_;
                $_->send_binary($msg) for $conn->server->connections;
            },
            pong => sub {
                my ($conn, $msg) = @_;
                $_->send_utf8($msg) for $conn->server->connections;
            },
            disconnect => sub {
                my ($conn, $code, $reason) = @_;
                say "Client: disconnect IP $conn->{ip} PORT $conn->{port}";
            },
        );
    },
)->start;
```

Client

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use IO::Async::Loop;
use Net::Async::WebSocket::Client;

my $HOST = '192.168.1.160';
my $PORT = 8080;

my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;

my $client = Net::Async::WebSocket::Client->new(
   on_text_frame => sub {
      my ( $self, $frame ) = @_;
      say $frame;
   },
);

my $input = IO::Async::Stream->new_for_stdin(
    on_read => sub {
        my ( $self, $buffref, $eof ) = @_;

        my $msg;

        $msg = $1 while $$buffref =~ s/^(.*)\n//;

        $client->send_text_frame( $msg );

        $loop->loop_stop if $msg eq 'exit';

        return 0;
    },
);

$loop->add( $client );
$loop->add( $input  );

$client->connect(
   url => "ws://$HOST:$PORT/"
)->then( sub {
    say 'Successfully connected to server';
    $client->send_text_frame( scalar localtime );
})->get;

$loop->run;

say 'Bye, until next time';

exit 0;
```

References:

- [Net::WebSocket::Server](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::WebSocket::Server)
- [Net::Async::WebSocket::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Async::WebSocket::Client)
- [IO::Async::Loop](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::Loop)

Comment: I altered the above code snippets to reflect my server and port origin and ran the codes. Both snippets executed successfully however client process is not displaying any output upon successful connection with server. I terminated the client code and server displayed client disconnected messages. Can we modify the codes to reflect message exchange between server and client upon successful connection?

Comment: message exchange is not happening between server / client processes.

Comment: You need do network troubleshooting, for simplicity try to turn firewall for a test and see if it changes the output. In my case I used Ubuntu 20.04 on same computer for server and client, both worked nicely and server was sending 'on_tick' messages for at least an hour.

Comment: I am also using server and client on same computer but still no messages exchange is taking place.

Comment: I am on windows 10.

Comment: Well, then you need to learn how to use Windows 10 firewall and how to configure it. [Best practices for configuring Windows Defender Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/best-practices-configuring) or call Microsoft and ask for their assistance, they will inform you how much they will charge you for their consultation.

Comment: [How to Find and Use the Windows 10 Firewall](https://www.lifewire.com/windows-10-firewall-4145353)